# Position an element fixed without removing it from Document flow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've three elements in my HTML code. I want to position the element fixed to the right side without removing it from the document flow.

```
<div class="container">
   <header class="main-header">
   </header>
   <main class="main-content">
   </main>
   <footer class="main-footer">
   </footer>
</div>
```

Here is the css code i'm using

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
.main-header{
   grid-column: 1/2;
   grid-row: 1/3;
   /* Here i want this to be fixed (scrolling should not have any effect)*/
   position: fixed;
  }
```

position fixed remove it from the Document flow and everything look ugly.
Can anybody tell me how to achieve this without using position:fixed; or without removing it from the document flow.

Answer (score 5):

Add an additional wrapping element around the `header` and then apply `position:sticky` to the `header`.

I have assumed you meant fixed to the *left* rather than *right* since this seems to be what was in your examples.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.con {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.wrap {
  background: gray
}

header {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

main {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.4);
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="wrap">
    <header>
      <h2>Someone</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsem</p>
      <p>lorem Ipsem</p>
      <p>lorem ipsem</p>
    </header>
  </div>
  <main>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae molestias maiores voluptates, suscipit eveniet vitae harum id? Fugiat labore eligendi delectus, ipsum molestiae numquam ex inventore deleniti deserunt quia perspiciatis!</p>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis atque enim possimus error voluptas distinctio eos vel? Dolorem alias voluptas minus sunt asperiores consequuntur! Sit harum qui culpa ea assumenda!
    </p>
    <h2>heaing 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut reprehenderit vero perferendis aspernatur, rerum asperiores! Aperiam aliquam commodi quod dolores, unde optio repellat necessitatibus facere, laborum expedita enim soluta.
    </p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Made by Zullu</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: could you share the reason for needing the wrapping around the header element ?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the header fixed and give .main-content a padding-top as big as the height of your header, or even a bit heigher for estetics.

```
.main-header{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  /* Here i want this to be fixed (scrolling should not have any effect)*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
}
.main-content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Seinfeld/pen/qLwaOj?editors=1100 please check this code and tell me what's wrong with it I want it to fixed on the right side but at the same time it should be the part of document flow

Comment: please check my version https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoQaGe?editors=1100

Comment: Your code is working correctly But i need to use grid while you are using float left.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with grid :) How about that? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXjqxM?editors=1100