# Have child div respect a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using `Tailwind CSS` and I wanted my navbar on the side to be fixed. As a result, it seems like the div adjacent to it (the dashboard) is now behind the nav bar, almost similar to it being absolute.

[image]

There should be a gap above

### Parent

```
    <div className="relative h-full min-h-screen flex overflow-y">
      <Sidebar />
      <Dashboard />
    </div>
```

### Sidebar

```
<div className={`flex fixed ${open ? "min-w-[18rem]" : "min-w-[5rem]"} z-0 min-h-screen flex-col shadow-2xl overflow-y bg-white`}
```

Comment: `fixed` and `absolute` are in that sense similar, in that they both remove the element from the document flow. Does this question answer yours?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217897/19529102

Comment: It sure does, thanks @Lord-JulianXLII!

Comment: I spoke too soon. My div  in the main container is high, but the sidebar isn't staying fixed. Anything required to keep the sidebar fixed? I have it wrapped in a div and the sidebar has sticky

Comment: Looks like I needed to add top-0